# Can we get a warning about indentation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I feel like over the past few days I've seen about a dozen questions in the `python` tag that have clearly had their indentation killed by a copy+paste. [This one, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137454/2-d-integration-in-python), should almost certainly have everything after the `def` indented one more time. Likewise for the [first revision here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29138412/revisions).

Both of these users seem to be reasonably familiar with Python and probably just overlooked the fact that their formatting got killed in copy+pasting. Is there any way we could get a warning for low-rep users posting in tags corresponding to whitespace-sensitive languages saying something like:

> Hey! The indentation in your post looks funky. Are you sure that it didn't get messed up when you pasted in code?

Comment: If two or more lines are indented more than 4 spaces (given the previous non-empty line is not indented), give 'em the auto post block message.

Comment: Related:http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281703/automatic-code-style-suggestions

Comment: This seems to apply to most languages, but blocking might cause problems to people on codegolf using [Whitespace](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Whitespace)