# Can we add a button "Format with Prettier" to the toolbar when editing posts?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, formatting

[Prettier](https://prettier.io/) supports formatting Markdown text and a bunch of languages. Can we add it as a button or format on save?

All the posts will have a unified look and feel, without the extra spaces, wrong indentations, lists with different styles, etc.

Comment: To do what? Does it replace the current editor? Something else? What is wrong with the current WMD editor / markdown formatting?

Comment: @rene: https://prettier.io/

Comment: @rene: Presumably, it prettifies the code you post.

Comment: There's a bit more to implementing Prettier than "add[ing] it as a button". Since the [browser implementation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/browser.html) requires plugins and parsers to be loaded when calling `format`. That could be challenging. It's not as easy as adding it to your favorite IDE.

Comment: And Prettier only seems to support [web application things](https://prettier.io/docs/en/index.html).  I feel like any tool we choose to do this would have to be more inclusive.

Comment: @AdamRackis The question is not tagged as a `feature-request`, so it won't get found as one, even if Stack Overflow were interested in rewriting that part of their code base... There's good reason to vote to close the question as written. Please [edit] the question if you find value in it.

Comment: alternatively, add indent buttons for highlighted lines (which may be more complicated)

Comment: It might help if you edit your question to explain why you think this is needed.

Comment: This opens up some interesting additional questions. Would you want the [Prettier default configuration](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html)? If so, you would be using a tab width of 2 spaces, amongst other things.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, as the other one is talking only about formatting code, while I'm talking about formatting the whole thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let's have a "Tidy Up" button!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261249/lets-have-a-tidy-up-button)

Comment: Let's not apply this for Python, though -- from what I've heard, formatting matters in that language.

Comment: (1) this definetly has to be optional (sometimes weird formatting matters, prettier doesnt support everything, etc.) (2) this definetly has to lazy load, as Prettier is quite a large library. And I agree that some kind of clarification would be helpful, but this definetly not *unclear*.

Comment: @JonasWilms it's clear that it has to do *something* it's not clear *what* or *why*. Specifics should be added. It's currently a vague suggestion, not a good feature request. I wouldn't be surprised if half the people who upvoted it did it for a different reason than the other half and neither actually considered the other group's motive.

Comment: @vlaz sure, the original question was tagged [discussion] so I think this was just meant as a starting point for, well, discussion, and wasn't at all meant to be a final, fully thought-out fr. Then the fr tag was edited in, and then it was closed for that.

Comment: I'm still not convinced there's a problem here, or at least not one that can be solved with an automated tool. Prettifying the markdown seems like an enormous waste of dev time to me, and as for actual code, there's lots of disagreement on styling (what is "wrong" indentation to you might be fine for someone else) and the people who don't bother proofreading their formatting before they post probably aren't going to even notice the button is there.

Comment: I agree that some sort of version of this feature would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The Prettier team started an [extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/prettier/fbcfnmplppajblbmdehballiekfgdkhp).